# Cannot read property 'x' of undefined. second level in json file

Tags: javascript, json

Problem : Can not render second level in the JSON file for some reason but first level works. Second level is giving me undefined error. Please help.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <li data-item="item1">1<p></p><span></span></li>
  <li data-item="item2">2<p></p><span></span></li>
  <li data-item="item3">3<p></p><span></span></li>
  <li data-item="item4">4<p></p><span></span></li>

</div>
```

**JS/JSON**

```
var data = [
    {
        "word": "hello",
        "favnumber": "0070",
        "item": "item1",
        "color": "red"
   },
   {
        "word": "hello world",
        "favnumber": "0233070",
        "item": "item2",
        "color": "blue",
       "Promo": {
            "Price": 3.99
        }
   },
   {
        "word": "hello mom",
        "favnumber": "0070",
        "item": "item3",
        "color": "pink",
       "Promo": {
            "Price": 4.99
        }
   },
   {
        "word": "hello dad",
        "favnumber": "0070",
        "item": "item4",
        "color": "silver",
        "Promo": {
            "Price": 8.99
        }
   }    
];

var items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-item]');

for (var e in items) {
    var element = items[e];
    var name = $(element).attr('data-item');

    for (var i in data) {
        var item = data[i];

        if (name == item.item) {
            var colorValue = item.color
            var promoPriceValue = item.Promo.Price //this doesn't work//
            $(element).find('p').text(colorValue)//this works//
            $(element).find('span').text(promoPriceValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/icovermaface/24L02a1q/1/

Comment: Please provide an example of your problem/JSON/code in your question

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle with the issue created. With the HTML, JSON and JS. http://jsfiddle.net/icovermaface/24L02a1q/1/

Comment: Please also include the JSON/JS in your question rather than just the jsfiddle.  The jsfiddle can contain a more complete example, but your question can provide a pared-down example of the code and JSON.

Comment: Hi @ExplosionPills, I have edited the post . I hope this is what you mean. Thanks

Comment: Your first item does not have a "Promo" member. If you look at a debugger it will most likely tell you that `var promoPriceValue = item.Promo.Price` throws an error because `item.Promo` is undefined, try `item.Promo ? item.Promo.Price : 'no promo'`. And remember the debugger is your friend.

Comment: @Prusse Thanks, I will give it a try

Comment: @Prusse it works! Quick question what does the '?' mean in between 'item.Promo' and 'item.Promo.Price'

Comment: It is a ternary conditional operator. There is some nice documentation for it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). `v = a ? a : b;` is logically equivalent to `if (a) { v = a; } else { v = b; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to not all your objects in `data` having the exact same data-structure, I would change your `for` loops from the `for ... in` pattern to an iterated variable since you are *iterating* over an array and not *enumerating* over a javascript object.  In other words:

```
for(var e=0; e < items.length; e++)
```

and

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
```

Here is some more info on why not to use the `for ... in` pattern with arrays: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Good link for explanation of `for...in` issues. +1

Comment: thanks @Jason..I have tried this method and it works perfect if all JSON has the same field. For example the first item in the array doesn't have 'Promo' and your method didn't work until I added 'Promo' in the  first field.

Answer (score 1):

The first item in your array doesnt have a `Promo` field. This is throwing the undefined error. Do a check to see if the field exists before trying to access it or create a default value

#### check

```
if(item.Promo) {
    var promoPriceValue = item.Promo.Price
}
```

#### default

```
var promoPriceValue = item.Promo ? item.Promo.Price : 10.99
```

Also you should change your loop structure, to a for `(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)` as Jason mentioned. As structured they throw this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getAttribute' in 4

working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/24L02a1q/7/

Comment: Thanks, I will double check